# How to rename index.php to home.php

Tags: htaccess

I rename `index.php` to `home.php` and put a flash in `index.php`. In the flash I make an effect and after it played 5 minutes it redirects to `home.php`.

I put this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /home.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

in my `.htaccess` file.

I turned on the permalinks to `example.com/sample-post` and all the posts links are ok. But `example.com/home.php` is not ok. If I set permalinks to `example.com/?p=123` all the links are not ok. The `example.com/home.php` is ok. The home page content is from `themes/mytheme/index.php`.

How to correct `example.com/home.php`?

what i want:

i want to add a flash to my site,namely,when access my site, first shows the flash, after some minutes,then redirect to the home page. on the flash, there is a link "enter to the website".

the way i am able to think is the following, in the flash i add code

stop();getURL('example.com/index.php','_self').
then create a file named index.php. put the invoke flash code in it. then rename the default index.php name to "fhp.php".

but it's not work. how to correct it?

Answer (score 5):

> how to correct example.com/home.php?

First, put things back the way you found them. [Both `index.php` and `home.php` are reserved file names.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#The_Template_Hierarchy_In_Detail) And `index.php` is special not only to WordPress but to the server itself-- [look into `DirectoryIndex`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html). You should not be manipulating them in this way. Unless you really know what you are doing you will cause trouble for yourself.

If you want to force your user to watch your Flash animation, which I strongly discourage-- I would leave your site and never return, plus iOS does not support Flash and [Adobe has stopped making the mobile player for Android](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260901/android_flash_player_rip_how_to_get_it_now_that_its_gone.html)-- you probably want something like:

```
function force_feed_flash() {
    if (is_home() || is_front_page()) {
        wp_safe_redirect(home_url('your_flash_page'));
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect','force_feed_flash');
```

Your Flash player can redirect back to the proper site when it is done. I am not sure I have the condition for the redirect right, but you should be able to work out when you want the redirect to occur and when you don't.

Comment: when i change home.php to homepg.php. it  still not work.why

Comment: i put your code in function.php. the home page still not work.

Comment: i put a link in the flash. "enter the site" the code is stop();getURL('http://www.example.com/index.php','_self'). but it redirect to http://www.example.com/home.php

Comment: If [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714441/why-this-way-in-wordpress-doesnt-work) is an indication, what you have done is not what I said to do.

Comment: i tried you have told,it doesn't work. when i  access the home page.

Comment: I'm sorry. You haven't put everything back the way it was or your URL for the flash page is wrong. This is a very simple thing to do. Or maybe your ActionScript is wrong-- no idea about that. I do know that the post on [so] that you have now removed still talked about renaming `index.php`.

Comment: i have tried your ways but it not work,so i post a new post want to know there is another way?thank you

Comment: stop();getURL('example.com/index.php','_self'). but it redirect to example.com/firsthp.php,  this is the ActionScript. the index.php invoke the flash code.firsthp.php code is define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require('./wp-blog-header.php');